# Powershell API request with cookies

Tags: powershell, curl

I am trying to make an API request in Powershell.

**The curl command that works:**

```
curl -k -v -X GET -H "Cookie: customer=<valueA>;JSESSIONID=<ValueB>" -H "Accept: application/json" https://someurl.net/path/path
```

I Tried:

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$cookie = New-Object System.Net.Cookie
$cookie2 = New-Object System.Net.Cookie

$cookie.Name = "customer"
$cookie.Value = "<valueA>"
$cookie.Domain = "https://someurl.net"

$cookie2.Name = "JSESSIONID"
$cookie2.Value = "<valueB>"
$cookie2.Domain = "https://someurl.net"

$session.Cookies.Add($cookie, $cookie2);

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://someurl.net/path/path" -Method Get -WebSession $session -Headers  @{"accept"="application/json"}
```

This should return a json payload. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of headers, use `-ContentType 'application\json'`.  Are your domains valid?

Comment: Changing the content type didn't seem to help. I'm using the domain of the web site that I am trying to access.

Comment: are you getting an error message or just a null return?  if your getting a weird object back Invoke-RestMethod might be worth a try

Answer (score 1):

Here might be the problem:

`$session.Cookies.Add($cookie, $cookie2);`

According to definition:

```
PS C:\> $session.Cookies.Add

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void Add(System.Net.Cookie cookie)
void Add(System.Net.CookieCollection cookies)
void Add(uri uri, System.Net.Cookie cookie)
void Add(uri uri, System.Net.CookieCollection cookies)
```

You should change it to:

```
$session.Cookies.Add($cookie);
$session.Cookies.Add($cookie2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried that and no-go.